# To "bring" or "take" cooking

Tags: word-usage, word-request

I'm aware that "cooking" can be used as a noun meaning "cooked food."

When I Google for phrases like "bring my cooking to," though, most sentences are as follows (which isn't the usage I want):

> ... bring my cooking to the next level.

There are almost no instances like this one:

> ... bring my cooking here.

Maybe the second usage is unusual? If so, what's a more common alternative?

Comment: The first usage isn't referring to the food, but to the act of preparing it.

Comment: For a start it would be "take" not "bring" -- "bring" has implications of "here", while "his house" has a sort of "there" feel. But apart from that, you may say "take some of my cooking to his house" or "take him a sample of my cooking", perhaps.

Comment: @PrimeMover Right, I changed that to "bring here."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first example, "cooking" doesn't mean "cooked food", but "the process or skill of preparing food".  "Take it to the next level" means improve my skill at something. It doesn't mean "Take my cooked food to a higher floor".

"Cooking" doesn't normally mean "cooked food".  It may be a process, a skill, or a style of cooking food.

Instead you might say "the food" or "the dish" or name the food "the lasagne"

> Please bring the dishes here.

> I'll bring my curried chicken with me when I visit.